# Can I create a Mac OS batch file to enable me to add a new account on OneDrive for Business after the installation

Tags: macos

Can I create a Mac OS batch file to enable me to add a new accounts on OneDrive for Business after the installation, below is the lines I used to type on the terminal but I need to automate it;

defaults write com.microsoft.OneDrive-mac DefaultToBusinessFRE -bool True

defaults write com.microsoft.OneDrive-mac EnableAddAccounts -bool True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just put them in a `bash` script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set up OneDrive for Business
defaults write com.microsoft.OneDrive-mac DefaultToBusinessFRE -bool True
defaults write com.microsoft.OneDrive-mac EnableAddAccounts -bool True
```

and save that on your Desktop as `OneDriveAddNew`.

Then start `Terminal`, by doing

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>

and starting to type `Terminal` till it guesses, then press `Enter`.

Now type the following (just one time) to make the script executable

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/OneDriveAddNew
```

Then you can just double-click the icon on your Desktop in order to run it.

Just for your understanding, note that the `chmod` command means... *"**Ch**ange the **M**ode of the script by adding the e**X**ecutable feature"*.

Also, by way of explanation, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, is called a *"Spotlight search"*.

Note that if you create a `bash` script using `TextEdit`, you must save it as `Plain Text` not `Rich Text Format`, so you will need to click on `Format` in `TextEdit's` menu and be sure it shows you are using Plain Text.